# mdframed box chips to the next page unnecessarily

Tags: mdframed

[image]

As shown in the picture, the problem box (inplemented with mdframed, see code from 133 to 139) has a small portion on the next page without any text. Giving extra margin on the top or bottom of the pages does not fix this. How can I fix this?
The environment is defined as:

```
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]                                  
        {\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray!20] \textbf{#1 #2} \\}
        {\end{mdframed}}
```

Comment: Use the tcolorbox package instead.

Comment: Thankyou very much! @UlrikeFischer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem seems to be solved according to the OPs comment.